# What is the difference between rewind() and clear() of class ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Note that in JDK document's words [`rewind()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind--) and [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#clear--) looks alike for "cleaning" the [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind--). Actually the old data exists, furthermore `rewind()` should be used before channel-write or get operation and `clear()` corresponds to channel-read or put operation.

I feel confused about the given description. What is the difference between these counterparts on earth?

Answer (score 5):

A difference is that `clear` resets the limit to the capacity, therefore preparing your buffer for other data to be written (and read by you), whereas `rewind` doesn't do anything to the limit, therefore your data may be read again.

Comment: Did you mean rewind ain't buffer cleaner but just preparation for buffer read operation?

Comment: Neither method actually clears the data inside the buffer. Only some indicators get changed.

Answer (score 4):

1) Here is clear() method:

```
public final Buffer clear() {
    position = 0;
    limit = capacity;
    mark = -1;
    return this;
}
```

The clear( ) method resets a buffer
to an empty state. It doesn't change any of the data elements of the buffer but simply sets the
limit to the capacity and the position back to 0

2) Here is rewind() method:

```
 public final Buffer rewind() {
    position = 0;
    mark = -1;
    return this;
}
```

You can use rewind( ) to go back and reread the data in a buffer that has already
been flipped. As you can see: it doesn't change the limit. Sometimes, after read data from a buffer, you may want to read it again, rewind() is the right choice for you.